# adding ip with forwarding rules in google cloud

Tags: ssl, ip, google-compute-engine, forwarding

Can anyone provide a tutorial on how I could add additional IP to my instance via forwarding in google cloud?

The current documentation is too complicated and not helpful. It does not state where the command should be executed and instruction is too vague.

I've been trying to setup a new instance, but I could not understand how I could setup the forwarding of all traffic on this instance to other instance. I would highly appreciate if someone could shine a light on this topic.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understood your question differently (compared to the other answer). I understand you need a second public IP pointing to an instance that already has its own public IP. If that is the case, follow these steps:

1. Let's start with the SDK, since you mention:

   > It does not states where the command should be executed and
   >   instruction is too vague

The commands are executed in your terminal once you have [downloaded and installed Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). In Linux/OS X it would be:

```
    curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

There's a 3-step guide in that link with more information.

2. Issue the command:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances list
   ```

to get a list of your instances and the zone they belong to. Take note of the NAME and the ZONE of the instance you need to work with. Notice the REGION needed in the commands below, is the first part of the ZONE field. (For example: ZONE: us-central1-f, then REGION is us-central1)

3. [Create a static public IP](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/create) to receive the traffic you want to forward:

   ```
   gcloud compute addresses create NAME
   gcloud compute addresses create targ-ip-1
   ```

where NAME is again, of your choice. It will prompt for the *region* (pick the same region where your instance is). This command will return an IP, let's say: W.X.Y.Z

4. You then need to [create a target-instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-instances/create):

   ```
   gcloud compute target-instances create NAME --instance INSTANCE
   gcloud compute target-instances create targ-ins-1 --instance instance-1
   ```

where NAME is a name of your choice for the target instance. INSTANCE is the name of the instance which will be handling traffic from one or more forwarding rules. It will prompt for the *zone* (pick the same zone where your instance is).

You can also create [target-pools](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-pools/create) to point to several instances at the same time, instead of just a target instance.

5. [Create the forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create), using the target instance and the static public IP you just created:

   ```
   gcloud compute forwarding-rules create NAME --address ADDRESS --target-instance TARGET_INSTANCE --target-instance-zone TARGET_INSTANCE_ZONE --ip-protocol IP_PROTOCOL --port-range [PORT | PORT-PORT]
   gcloud compute forwarding-rules create fwd-rule-1 --address W.X.Y.Z --target-instance targ-ins-1 --target-instance-zone us-central1-f --ip-protocol TCP --port-range 5678-5680
   ```

where:

- NAME: a name of your choice for the forwarding rule
- ADDRESS: the IP address you reserved in step 3
- TARGET_INSTANCE: the target instance name you created in step 4
- TARGET_INSTANCE_ZONE: the zone where your target instance belongs to
- IP_PROTOCOL (optional): The IP protocol that the rule will serve. If left empty, TCP is used. Supported protocols are: AH, ESP, SCTP, TCP, UDP.
- PORT (optional): If specified, only packets addressed to ports in the specified range will be forwarded. If not specified, all ports are matched

You will be prompted to select a *region* where this rule will belong to.

To verify your rule, you can [list your configured forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/list) like this:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
```

You should start receiving traffic pointing to the new public IP, in the instance you chose.

Comment: Doesn't work in the case you need your machine to send data back... (from a separate 'connection'), it will be sent from the instance's default external ip... do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @Gizmo Here's an idea, although I haven't tested any of this. You could use iptables to send traffic back with the other IP. You need to: 1) set `ip forwarding` to `on` for that instance in google cloud console, 2) in the server, configure sysctl: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`, and 3) in the server, configure iptables to change the originating IP (maybe something like this, but as I said, it's just to give you a hint, hasn't been tested): `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <SERVER PRIVATE IP> -d <DESTINATION IP (in case it is static?)> -j SNAT --to-source <PUBLIC IP YOU WANT TO DISPATCH FROM>`

Comment: @Gizmo I don't really think the ip forwarding stuff is necessary.. I got the iptables idea because I use it to change the originating IP from packets being forwarded in a VPN gateway. It does work, but my destinations are static IPs. You would have to adjust for your case. I hope the idea helps.

Comment: @magnap oh nice idea! with multiple processes on the server I think that the iptables owner module should be able to make this work

Comment: Wow this works! Shame you need to create the VM with --can-ip-forward (had to delete my old VM's)

Comment: @Gizmo Thx for the feedback. Nice to know it does work   :)

Comment: Yeah I'm really glad it does :) per user ip's are nice. no need for a vm instance per user. (tho up to 18 users it's much cheaper to just have 18  micro VM's, compared to google's load balancer pricing), I also still don't get why cloud providers (a.k.a. GCE, Azure, EC2) don't allow multiple "public' NICs. Would make life so much easier.

Comment: can you bind nginx 1.1.1.1:80 and another on 2.2.2.2:80?

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato I don't know nginx enough to tell you how much you can "cheat" with it, but I don't think you can do that. In this case, the OP is asking to route a second IP address to the same instance. You don't really have a second IP address assigned to a second interface in that instance, so, as far as I understand, asking xginx to bind to the second interface won't be possible. There might be a workaround for what you need, but I can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: @maganap I`m not into network world, but it is really bad if you can't bind some service on 1.1.1.1:80 and another on 2.2.2.2:80 ...

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato You can certainly bind a service to 2 different interfaces. I was just trying to make clear that, in the case of this question, the server doesn't have a second interface. It is just an IP being forwarded to the instance, but that second IP is not attached to the instance itself.

Comment: @maganap Maybe we are talking about https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/alias-ip/

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I see that you would like to **setup a routing rule so that all the traffic from an instance is routed through another instance**.

It shouldn't be too complicated to setup, the best example I can think to give you at this time is the setup used in the ["Configuring a NAT gateway"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) guide from the Google Help Center docs.

Pay attention to the following more specifically (from step 5 in the guide):

```
$ gcloud compute routes create no-ip-internet-route --network gce-network \
     --destination-range 0.0.0.0/0 \
     --next-hop-instance nat-gateway \
     --next-hop-instance-zone us-central1-a \
     --tags no-ip --priority 800
```

We can break that down to better understand exactly what that rule does:

1. We're creating a route within the "gce-network" and we're calling it "no-ip-internet-route".
2. The `--destination-range 0.0.0.0/0` is to specify that traffic meant for any destination should be affected by the rule. We're referring to traffic that will be leaving our instance.
3. The `--next-hop-instance nat-gateway` part is to specify that after triggering the rule, traffic should be sent to the 'nat-gateway' instance as a next hop.
4. `--next-hop-instance-zone us-central1-a` is just to specify the zone of our gateway machine.
5. `--tags no-ip --priority 800` is used to say that only instances with the 'no-ip' tag on them should be affected (as long as they are in the network in which this rule is being created) and we're also setting a 'higher' priority on the rule to ensure it takes precedence over other rules.

With all of the above taken into consideration, any instance that has the 'no-ip' tag would always pass it's outgoing traffic to the 'nat-gateway' instance. In summary, the 'nat-gateway' instance automatically becomes the 'next-hop' for all outgoing traffic from a tagged instance.

You can use a similar setup to figure out your routing rules and create them based on this one, however please note that the 'nat-gateway' used in this example has specific capabilities such as IP forwarding and essentially acts as a router and becomes the default gateway for instances tagged with the rule.

**You also asked**: how to add additional ip to my instance via forwarding in google cloud?

Technically, you could just add your instance in a ['target pool'](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/target-pools) and then create a [forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules), to forward desired traffic to that instance. The forwarding rule will give you an additional IP address. This can also be used to SSH to the instance via the forwarding rule's IP address as long as you're forwarding traffic on port 22 or what ever port the instance is set to listen on.

Comment: thank you, ive figured it from the documentation after some try and error :) and i found out that i was using the wrong project id, and thats where my command line failed...